# Embedded Ifelse Statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, dcast

I have a dataset as follows:

```
Source     Rev_Diff    Cost_Diff     Price_Diff      Sales_Diff      
     A          -10           10             11              12
     B           11          -10            -10              11
     C          -12           10             10             -11
     D          -11          -11            -10             -12
```

How do I add a column where:

"If Rev_Diff is less than 0, 
print "Cost" if "Cost_Diff" with amount is less than 0, 
print "Price" if "Price_Diff" with amount is less than 0, 
print "Sales" if  "Sales_Diff" with amount is less than 0,
else print "We're up".

Final Output:

```
Source     Rev_Diff    Cost_Diff     Price_Diff      Sales_Diff      Reason Down     
     A          -10          -10             11              12      Cost (-10) 
     B           11          -10            -10              11      We're Up
     C          -12           10             10             -11      Sales (-11)
     D          -11          -11            -10             -12      Cost (-11), Price (-11), Sales (-12)
```

Comment: Maybe use `max.col` and next time consider making a less complicated example (like, not having "rev" point to "cost", etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't quite get your how you want to structure your if statements but the following can add a new column based on the info in a previous column.

```
Source <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
Rev_Diff <- c(-10, 11, 12, 11, 10)
Cost_Diff <- c(10, -10, 10, -11, 11)
Price_Diff <- c(-11, 10, -10, 10, 10)
Sales_Diff <- c(12, 11, 11, -12, 11)

df <- data.frame(Source, Rev_Diff, Cost_Diff, Price_Diff, Sales_Diff)

df %>% 
  mutate(ReasonDown = ifelse(Rev_Diff < 0, paste("Rev", Rev_Diff),
                      ifelse(Cost_Diff < 0, paste("Cost", Cost_Diff),
                      ifelse(Price_Diff < 0, paste("Price", Price_Diff),
                      ifelse(Sales_Diff < 0, paste("Sales", Sales_Diff), "We're up")))))

  Source Rev_Diff Cost_Diff Price_Diff Sales_Diff ReasonDown
1      A      -10        10        -11         12    Rev -10
2      B       11       -10         10         11   Cost -10
3      C       12        10        -10         11  Price -10
4      D       11       -11         10        -12   Cost -11
5      E       10        11         10         11   We're up
```

However, ifelse will stop once it finds a TRUE statement, so this will not be able to print out multiple "Down Reasons" like you had in Source D. If you really want to print everything, I think you should be able to add 4 new columns to check on each of Rev, Cost, Price, Sales, and add a 5th column to sum up everything.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(RRev = ifelse(Rev_Diff < 0, paste("Rev", Rev_Diff), "")) %>% 
  mutate(RCost = ifelse(Cost_Diff < 0, paste("Cost", Cost_Diff), "")) %>%
  mutate(RPrice = ifelse(Price_Diff < 0, paste("Price", Rev_Diff), "")) %>%
  mutate(RSales = ifelse(Sales_Diff < 0, paste("Sales", Rev_Diff), "")) %>% 
  mutate(DownReason = ifelse(nchar(paste(RRev, RCost, RPrice, RSales)) > 3, paste(RRev, RCost, RPrice, RSales), "We're UP"))

  Source Rev_Diff Cost_Diff Price_Diff Sales_Diff    RRev    RCost    RPrice   RSales          DownReason
1      A      -10        10        -11         12 Rev -10          Price -10          Rev -10  Price -10 
2      B       11       -10         10         11         Cost -10                             Cost -10  
3      C       12        10        -10         11                   Price 12                    Price 12 
4      D       11       -11         10        -12         Cost -11           Sales 11  Cost -11  Sales 11
5      E       10        11         10         11                                                We're UP
```

Comment: Thanks @JPHwang, how would you add the "We're Up" section for the last version?

Comment: You can use a single `mutate` to add multiple columns.

Comment: @NickKnauer changed last statement to count the number of characters, if everything is > 0 the paste will generate 3 blanks, so everything above that will print as usual  and 3 blanks will generate "We're up"

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the tip!